# What is the name of the piece that is often used to switch gears?

Tags: technic, part-identification, bricklink

I have been trying to find this part on BrickLink and have searched every Technic category.  I have come up empty.

Could someone provide the name of this part so that I can find it on BrickLink?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is [Part 6641 - Technic Changeover Catch](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6641).

Also known as ["Technic Transmission Changeover Catch"](http://www.peeron.com/inv/parts/6641).